# decoding base64 encoded text with POSIX awk

Tags: awk, base64, posix, openldap

I need to decode a lot of base64-encoded **text** strings in `awk`; because I don't want to massively fork a non-portable `base64` binary, I wrote an `awk` function for doing the decoding:

```bash
function base64_decode(str,    out,i,n,v) {
    out = ""
    if ( ! ("A" in _BASE64_DECODE_c2i) )
        for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
            _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",i,1)] = i-1
    i = 0
    n = length(str)
    while (i <= n) {
        v = _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,++i,1)] * 262144 + \
            _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,++i,1)] * 4096 + \
            _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,++i,1)] * 64 + \
            _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,++i,1)]
        out = out sprintf("%c%c%c", int(v/65536), int(v/256), v)
    }
    return out
}
```

Which works fine:

```bash
printf '%s\n' SmFuZQ== amRvZQ== |

LANG=C command -p awk '
    { print base64_decode($0) }
    function base64_decode(...) {...} # placeholder for the real function
'
```

```
Jane
jdoe
```

---

###### CONTEXTUAL PROBLEM

I' trying to get the `givenName` of the users that are members of `GroupCode` = `025496` from the output of `ldapsearch -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no ... '(|(uid=*)(GroupCode=*))' uid givenName GroupCode memberUid`, for example:

```
dn: uid=jsmith,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
givenName: John
uid: jsmith

dn: uid=jdoe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
uid: jdoe
givenName:: SmFuZQ==

dn: cn=group1,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
GroupCode: 025496
memberUid:: amRvZQ==
memberUid: jsmith
```

Here would be an `awk` for doing so:

```bash
LANG=C command -p awk -F '\n' -v RS='' -v GroupCode=025496 '
    {
        delete attrs
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            match($i,/::? /)
            key = substr($i,1,RSTART-1)
            val = substr($i,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            if (RLENGTH == 3)
                val = base64_decode(val)
            attrs[key] = ((key in attrs) ? attrs[key] SUBSEP val : val)
        }
        if ( /\nuid:/ )
            givenName[ attrs["uid"] ] = attrs["givenName"]
        else
            memberUid[ attrs["GroupCode"] ] = attrs["memberUid"]
    }
    END {
        n = split(memberUid[GroupCode],uid,SUBSEP)
        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            print givenName[ uid[i] ]
    }

    function base64_decode(...) { ... } # placeholder for the real function
'
```

On BSD and Solaris the result is:

```bash
Jane
John
```

While on Linux it is:

```bash
John
```

I don't understand where the issue is. Is there something wrong with the `base64_decode` function and/or the code that uses it?

Comment: fwiw, with `base64` (`GNU coreutils / 8.26`) I get `Jane` and `jdoe` ... not sure how/where the `John` comes from ... ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function generates NUL bytes when its argument (encoded string) ends with padding characters (`=`s). Below is a corrected version of your `while` loop:

```
while (i < n) {
    v = _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,1+i,1)] * 262144 + \
        _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,2+i,1)] * 4096 + \
        _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,3+i,1)] * 64 + \
        _BASE64_DECODE_c2i[substr(str,4+i,1)]
    i += 4
    if (v%256 != 0)
        out = out sprintf("%c%c%c", int(v/65536), int(v/256), v)
    else if (int(v/256)%256 != 0)
        out = out sprintf("%c%c", int(v/65536), int(v/256))
    else
        out = out sprintf("%c", int(v/65536))
}
```

Note that if the decoded bytes contains an embedded NUL then this approach may not work properly.

Comment: Thank you @MNejatAydin, Thats spot on, I completely forgot to handle the padding!!

Comment: "_an embedded NUL_" If there really is one then only GNU awk would be able to handle it. That's also why my original solution was working on BSD and Solaris: the superfluous `NUL` was treated as the end-of-string marker.

Comment: @Fravadona : ??? `mawk`s handle embedded `\0` just fine.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto what's the **oldest** mawk version that can handle `NUL` characters?

Comment: @Fravadona : can't say for certain, but one change note from `Sep 2014` mentioned `"+ fix a comparison in rexp3.c to work with embedded nulls (patch by
   Mike Brennan)."`, and that's a sub-version of 1.3.4. It's not like DECADES per se, but 8 1/4 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is within `base64_decode` function that outputs some junk characters on gnu-awk.

You can use this awk code that uses system provided `base64` utility as an alternative:

```bash
{
   delete attrs
   for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
      match($i,/::? /)
      key = substr($i,1,RSTART-1)
      val = substr($i,RSTART+RLENGTH)
      if (RLENGTH == 3) {
         cmd = "echo " val " | base64 -di"
         cmd | getline val   # should also check exit code here
      }
      attrs[key] = ((key in attrs) ? attrs[key] SUBSEP val : val)
   }
   if ( /\nuid:/ )
      givenName[ attrs["uid"] ] = attrs["givenName"]
   else
      memberUid[ attrs["GroupCode"] ] = attrs["memberUid"]
}
END {
   n = split(memberUid[GroupCode],uid,SUBSEP)
   for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
      print givenName[ uid[i] ]
}
```

I have tested this on gnu and BSD awk versions and I am getting expected output in all the cases.

If you cannot use external `base64` utility then I suggest you take a look here for [awk version of base64 decode](https://github.com/shane-kerr/AWK-base64decode/blob/master/base64decode.awk).

Comment: I've been reading the `base64decode` function and I spotted a few things that might cause problems (local variables that are global, using `/dev/stderr`, ...). It feels like It will be difficult to use it in my code.

Comment: Fair point about using an external call but current `base64_decode` code in question is broken on gnu-awk. Either we need a fix for that or some other variant that works same on all awk versions.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is for reference**

Here's a working `base64_decode` function (thanks @MNejatAydin for pointing out the issue(s) in the original one):

```bash
function base64_decode(str,    out,bits,n,i,c1,c2,c3,c4) {
    out = ""

    # One-time initialization during the first execution
    if ( ! ("A" in _BASE64) )
        for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
            # The "_BASE64" array associates a character to its base64 index
            _BASE64[substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",i,1)] = i-1

    # Decoding the input string
    n = length(str)
    i = 0
    while ( i < n ) {
        c1 = substr(str, ++i, 1)
        c2 = substr(str, ++i, 1)
        c3 = substr(str, ++i, 1)
        c4 = substr(str, ++i, 1)

        bits = _BASE64[c1] * 262144 + _BASE64[c2] * 4096 + _BASE64[c3] * 64 + _BASE64[c4]

        if ( c4 != "=" )
            out = out sprintf("%c%c%c", bits/65536, bits/256, bits)
        else if ( c3 != "=" )
            out = out sprintf("%c%c", bits/65536, bits/256)
        else
            out = out sprintf("%c", bits/65536)
    }

    return out
}
```

**WARNING:** the function **requires** `LANG=C`

It also doesn't check that the input is a valid base64 string; for that you can add a simple condition like:

```bash
match( str, "^([a-zA-Z/-9+]{4})*([a-zA-Z/-9+]{2}[a-zA-Z/-9+=]{2})?$" )
```

Interestingly, the code is 2x faster than [base64decode.awk](https://github.com/shane-kerr/AWK-base64decode/blob/master/base64decode.awk), but it's only 3x faster than forking the `base64` binary from inside `awk`.

---

**notes:**

1. In a `base64` encoded string, 4 bytes represent 3 bytes of data; the input have to be processed by groups of 4 characters.
2. Multiplying and dividing an integer by a power of two is equivalent to do bitwise left and right shifts operations.

   - `262144` is `2^18`, so `N * 262144` is equivalent to `N << 18`
   - `4096` is `2^12`, so `N * 4096` is equivalent to `N << 12`
   - `64` id `2^6`, so `N * 4096` is equivalent to `N << 6`
   - `65536` is `2^16`, so `N / 65536` (integer division) is equivalent to `N >> 16`
   - `256` is `2^8`, so `N / 256` (integer division) is equivalent to `N >> 8`
3. What happens in `printf "%c", N`:

   `N` is first converted to an integer (if need be) and then, **WITH** `LANG=C`, the **8 least significant bits** are taken in for the `%c` formatting.
4. Handling of the potential padding at the end of the encoded string:

   - If the 4<sup>th</sup> char **isn't** `=` (i.e. there's no padding) then the result should be 3 bytes of data.
   - If the 4<sup>th</sup> char **is** `=` **and** the 3<sup>rd</sup> char **isn't** `=` then there's 2 bytes of of data to decode.
   - If the fourth char **is** `=` **and** the third char **is** `=`  then there's only one byte of data.

---

Comment: at all the places for `sprintf("%c….)`, for each item, add an offset of `0xDC00` - then `gawk`-unicode mode could `b64`-decode binary files too.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto That's an interesting way to do the decoding

Comment: for my own b64 dec module, i always handle the final chunk first, if there are any `"="`. that way, the rest of them could go much faster instead of having to keep doing nested ternaries regarding how many equal signs. And that offset doesn't *have* to be exactly `0xDC00` - basically anything within the `UTF-16 surrogates` space that's congruent to `zero (mod 256)` will do

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto That will save `length(str)/4` of `c4 != "=" ` comparisons (I made sure to test it first), so your solution would go a  little bit faster; if there's a huge number of data to decode then it'll be relevant.

Comment: another approach i've been contemplating but haven't fully hashed out is simply jot down how many equal signs at the tail, call this `k`, replace those `"="` with  `"A"`s (thus contributing zero value, as desired), which *should* decode to trailing edge `NUL` bytes. When all is said and done, trim out `k` number of bytes from the tail. Do you think this would work ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto I don't think that will work. Some `awk`s treat the `NUL` byte as the end-of-string, so stripping them isn't necessary (that was the issue in the question). For the others, copying the whole string just to strip the padded NUL bytes feels like a waste. I think that treating the last byte differently, outside of the loop, would be the fastest solution, and will double the size of the code.

Comment: ahhhh okay. side note : my other friend was shocked when he heard that `awk` is THIS fast, despite all scalars being passed by value.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Well, under the hood, some `awk` implementations might pass an argument by reference when it isn't modified inside the function.

Comment: and that's smart and prudent design indeed, as long as the pointers aren't exposed to the end-user codes. Just look at how many major security holes in `C` and `C++` stem from exploiting mismanagement of pointers.